# Asking the views of people about a past event

Tags: sentence-structure

I asked a question on Quora:

> Who had to be the Caliph of Muslims in the view of Sunnis? W or Z?

Or

> In the view of Sunnis, who should have been the Caliph of Muslims? W or Z?

---

In both cases Quora's moderator says I should modify it with this message:

> Your question may need editing to be easier to understand. Please double check for spelling, phrasing, or other mistakes.

Which could be a fixed message for any question which is not follow English grammars or is not fluent.

What is the problem of each and which one is preferred?

As a context, it refers to a conflict happened 1400 years ago; and both Shia and Sunni have the same opinions over it.

Comment: **had to be** can express the idea that something was unavoidable, that something other than it could not have happened, whereas **should have been** expresses the idea that something was desirable or legitimate or appropriate.   We can also use **have to** to express a strong or compelling reason or desire to do something (*We have to elect him president!*) but in your case **should have been** is the better choice, since the idea is *legitimacy*.

Comment: Ahmad, when you are experiencing an issue like that one, you should flag the comments for the moderation team to handle and not try to argue with people yourself. This is a fine English question now that it has been clarified.

Comment: @ColleenV but he as maybe others misunderstood me, and accused me for some political things which was inaccurate. I don't know how can I defend myself!

Comment: Ahmad, ELL isn't for political discussion. They shouldn't have turned your question into a political discussion, and you don't need to defend yourself. Flag the comments and forget about them. If you respond to inappropriate comments, you are contributing to the problem, and not the solution. Your moderation team is here to handle these situations so that you don't have to. Now, let's all get back to helping each other learn English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting aside the context of the question itself, I think the second sentence is easier to understand.  There is an unnecessary space before the question mark, and some missing articles, but otherwise it's perfectly grammatical:

> In the view of **the** Sunnis, who should have been the Caliph of **the** Muslims? Hassan/Hussain or Yazid?

It's possible that the moderator removed the question for some problem with context, but that's outside the scope of ELL.